# Comparison between two ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone objects fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone, activesupport

In my test suite, I have a failing test.

`expected[0]['date']` comes from `SomeModel.first.created_at`

In a debugging console, I have the following:

```
> expected[0]['date']
=> Tue, 25 Mar 2014 16:01:45 UTC +00:00
> res[0]['date']
=> Tue, 25 Mar 2014 16:01:45 UTC +00:00
> res[0]['date'] == expected[0]['date']
=> false # wtf
> res[0]['date'].class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
> expected[0]['date'].class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
>
```

How is this possible ?

I've tried to reproduce this problem (I tought maybe the == operator on TimeWithZone checks the reference, or something like this, but no...) :

```
> t1 = Time.zone.at(0)
=> Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
> t2 = Time.zone.parse(t1.to_s)
=> Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
> t1 == t2
=> true
> t1.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
> t2.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

---

*Edit*: More tests...

```
> res[0]['date'].eql?(expected[0]['date'])
=> false
> res[0]['date'].zone
=> "UTC"
> expected[0]['date'].zone
=> "UTC"
> expected[0]['date'].getlocal
=> 2014-03-25 16:01:45 +0000
> res[0]['date'].getlocal
=> 2014-03-25 16:01:45 +0000
> res[0]['date'].hash
=> -3455877575500291788
> expected[0]['date'].hash
=> -3819233736262144515
>
> t1.hash
=> 2279159074362527997
> t2.hash
=> 2279159074362527997

# inspect...
> expected[0]['date'].inspect
=> "Tue, 25 Mar 2014 16:39:01 UTC +00:00"
> res[0]['date'].inspect
=> "Tue, 25 Mar 2014 16:39:01 UTC +00:00"
```

Looks like the comparison is based on the hash object. Why res and expected have different `hash`es ?

Comment: Whats is res ? Have you tried to print res.inspect and expected.inspect ?

Comment: @vdaubry Added inspect

Comment: Having this same issue - did you figure it out?

Comment: Added a few different answers for how to resolve this while testing, not sure if any of them will be useful for everyone, but I was able to resolve my problem following Answer #2 (Spring/Rspec).

Answer (score 1):

**Answer #1** `rake db:test:prepare`

First, attempt dropping the test database and recreating it, and then running `rake db:test:prepare`. This has resolved this issue for me in the past I know this is a bit of a lame answer, but it is worth a shot.

**Answer #2** Spring + Rspec + Shoulda matchers

If having this issue after installing **Spring**, please checkout this Github Thread, which can cause tests to fail:
https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/209

This issue only started occurring for me after adding Spring to my project.
Adding `gem 'shoulda', require: false` and manually adding `require 'shoulda/matchers'` to my `spec_helper.rb` resolved the issues

**Answer #3** Timecop

If still having issues, checkout the Timecop gem and freeze time around date comparisons.
https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop

Comment: It seems that the error comes frolm comparing the result of #to_f
I got around it by using only _aligned_ timestamps with my tests like e.g. 1.day.ago.noon

My guess would be that timecop does something similar.