# Rails/Ruby: TimeWithZone comparison inexplicably failing for equivalent values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, comparison

I am having a terrible time (no pun intended) with DateTime comparison in my current project, specifically comparing two instances of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone.  The issue is that both my TimeWithZone instances have the same value, but all comparisons indicate they are different.

Pausing during execution for debugging (using RubyMine), I can see the following information:

```
timestamp = {ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone} 2014-08-01 10:33:36 UTC
started_at = {ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone} 2014-08-01 10:33:36 UTC

timestamp.inspect = "Fri, 01 Aug 2014 10:33:36 UTC +00:00"
started_at.inspect = "Fri, 01 Aug 2014 10:33:36 UTC +00:00"
```

Yet a comparison indicates the values are not equal:

```
timestamp <=> started_at = -1
```

The closest answer I found in searching ([Comparison between two ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone objects fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640107/comparison-between-two-activesupporttimewithzone-objects-fails)) indicates the same issue here, and I tried the solutions that were applicable without any success (tried db:test:prepare and I don't run Spring).

Moreover, even if I try converting to explicit types, they still are not equivalent when comparing.

to_time:

```
timestamp.to_time = {Time} 2014-08-01 03:33:36 -0700
started_at.to_time = {Time} 2014-08-01 03:33:36 -0700

timestamp.to_time <=> started_at.to_time = -1
```

to_datetime:

```
timestamp.to_datetime = {Time} 2014-08-01 03:33:36 -0700
started_at.to_datetime = {Time} 2014-08-01 03:33:36 -0700

timestamp.to_datetime <=> started_at.to_datetime = -1
```

The **only** "solution" I've found thus far is to convert both values using `to_i`, then compare, but that's extremely awkward to code everywhere I wish to do comparisons (and moreover, seems like it should be unnecessary):

```
timestamp.to_i = 1406889216
started_at.to_i = 1406889216

timestamp.to_i <=> started_at.to_i = 0
```

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I strongly suspect that the values differ in fractions of a second. Try using `to_f` instead of `to_i`, and you may see the difference. Or format them to include fractions of a second.

Comment: @JonSkeet You got it, thanks so much!  I detailed the specifics in my edit to the original post, but long story short is one value was being retrieved from the database and the other was in memory, and since I was running on MySQL, the millisecond data was cut off just one value but not both.

Comment: @GabeStah you should post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## **Solved**

As indicated by Jon Skeet above, the comparison was failing because of hidden millisecond differences in the times:

```
timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L') = "2014-08-02 10:23:17.000"
started_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L') = "2014-08-02 10:23:17.679"
```

This discovery led me down a strange path to finally discover what was ultimately causing the issue.  It was a combination of this issue occurring *only* during testing and from using MySQL as my database.

The issues was showing only in testing because within the test where this cropped up, I'm running some tests against a couple of associated models that contain the above fields.  One model's instance must be saved to the database during the test -- the model that houses the `timestamp` value.  The other model, however, was performing the processing and thus is self-referencing the instance of itself that was created in the test code.

This led to the second culprit, which is the fact I'm using MySQL as the database, which when storing `datetime` values, *does not* store millisecond information (unlike, say, PostgreSQL).

Invariably, what this means is that the `timestamp` variable that was being read after its ActiveRecord was retrieved from the MySQL database was effectively being rounded and shaved of the millisecond data, while the `started_at` variable was simply retained in memory during testing and thus the original milliseconds were still present.

My own (sub-par) solution is to essentially force both models (rather than just one) in my test to retrieve themselves from the database.

**TLDR; If at all possible, use PostgreSQL if you can!**

Comment: FYI, MySQL supports millisecond times now, so no need to switch databases, but this Gotcha can still getcha when comparing persisted values with user-inputted values, etc. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

This seem to happen if you're comparing time generated in Ruby with time loaded from the database.

For example:

```
time = Time.zone.now
Record.create!(mark: time)
record = Record.last
```

In this case `record.mark == time` will fail because Ruby keeps time down to nanoseconds, while different databases have different precission.

In case of postgres DateTime type it'll be to miliseconds.

You can see that when you check that while `record.mark.sec == time.msec` - `record.mark.nsec != time.nsec`